# Audio issues Ubuntu 20.04/20.10

Tags: sound, speakers

So I bought a new Thinkbook 13s gen2 itl from Lenovo and surprise the audio doesn't come through the speakers in Linux I have tried three different Ubuntu variants and Pop Os! I have alsa and pulse installed tried uninstalling it and reinstall but still no sound through the speakers. Someone has said on another site it's a kernel issue but being it's a Tiger lake processor and brand new hardware who can say for sure I mean even in Windows there are issues like graphical glitching at full resolution with current drivers. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Tiger Lake requires Intel SOF firmware. To install:

```
sudo apt install firmware-sof-signed
```

And reboot. If sound works but the microphone doesn't try:

```
pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,7
```

Then change your Input source to the Tiger Lake option that doesn't mention multichannel. If that works, make it permanent by adding the following to the end of /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,7
```

Reference: [Linux Mint Forum Post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=326810)